# C++ DLL compiled with /clr used in winforms compiled with /clr:pure

Tags: c++, winforms, dll, unmanaged

I created a DLL to use in my project, however, I get the following error:

```
error C3389: __declspec(dllexport) cannot be used with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
```

which I sort of expected, but I figured I could use platform invoke, however, I found NO explanations of how to do this with C++.  Everything I found was C#.

Can anyone either explain or give me a link?

I have in the dll.h file:

```
static __declspec(dllexport) double name(function);
```

then the dll.cpp:

```
#include "dll.h"

namespace name
{
    double name::name(function)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

However I'm unsure what to change if I were to use `__clrcall`.